# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function JQUERY in MVC 4

Tags: jquery-ui, model-view-controller

i've got a problem in my jquery, first i render view i check using developer tools and got this error, so my button click is doesn't work. i need help to solve my problem

[image]

I render jquery in views with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

but i've got error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function searchemployee:39
(anonymous function) searchemployee:39
l jquery.js:2842
c.fireWith jquery.js:2954
x.extend.ready jquery.js:387
S
```

can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check you are not loading jquery.js twice.